# Add WPF templates to a class library project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I have a class library that is going to have some WPF UI. I've got the framework plugged in. Is there a way I can incorporate the "Add Item" WPF templates? As of now, I only have UserControl. I can create the files myself, but it would save me a lot of time to be able to add them in the IDE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit late but:

.NET projects have zero or more project types in the csproj file that enable/disable IDE features.

If you started from a class library and want to change it as if it were a WPF control library, you can just add these project types manually to the csproj file.

Add the `<ProjectTypes>` element as shown below to the `<PropertyGroup>` that also contains the `<ProjectGuid>`:

```
<Project ...>
  <ProjectGroup ...>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{64D2C408-BB81-4627-AF7C-672142229677}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Some.Client.WPFLib</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Some.Client.WPFLib</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>

    <!-- add this line: -->
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>

    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
  </ProjectGroup>
</Project>
```

These two guids are what you find in a WPF Application project and represent ProjectTypes "Windows C#" and "WPF". (http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)

Comment: Thanks. Worked great.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to create these types of classes, is to create a WPF Application project, and set the "Output type" in the Application tab of the project properties to "Class Library".

You can then delete the App.xaml, MainWindow, and any other files that aren't needed.

I use this approach to build a wide array of reusable themes, etc.

You will get all the standard WPF templates you expect when doing File > New.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I would rather have a solution that doesn't involve recreating my project.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
```

in `<Project><PropertyGroup>` node